# What is multiserver installation in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, multiserver

I'm not clear that what is the benefits of Multiserver installation in Coldfusion? Which benefits can I get when I installed like that in my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that you can have 1 CF project per CF instance.

Each instance can have their own webserver and CFAdmin settings (i.e. data source, mapping, etc.)

Very useful especially when you work on multiple projects.  (e.g. SiteA.dev maps to CF instance A, and SiteB.dev maps to CF Instance B)

Note: only available in Developer / Enterprise edition, not Standard.

If you're using Win 7 Pro, use IIS.  Otherwise, use Apache with virtual hostings (vhost.conf) to support multiple sites on your development machine.

Comment: If one application crush to cfserver, it won't effect to another application. Is that right?

Comment: right.  The default one is called "cfusion", then you can always log into the CF Administrator and start/stop/restart other instances you created.

Comment: I presume you can still kill off the machine if one instance of CF hogs all of some resource, such as CPU?

Comment: If one instance crush to the whole cfserver, the rest of application will be crushed either?

Comment: @ppshein Any decent OS will not let any one process to hog the CPU to a point that it cannot be killed, in theory. :)  So, in theory, no.

Comment: With multiple instances you can use jrun or coldfusion to cluster them. If one instance goes down then the others take up the slack.  That is a bit simplistic, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: That's great. I found the benefit of multi-instance. Before time, I installed my two applications in the same sever without using multi-instance. In these days, one application goes down, the others can't work anymore. That's why need to restart the whole CF service of my server. With multi-instance, I don't need to touch the CF services of my server hopefully.